# Importance of spelsource in spring integration

Tags: spring, integration

Can anyone help to understand the spelsource importance?

```
<bean id="spelSource" 
        class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory"> 
        <property name="parameterExpressions"> 
                <map> 
                        <entry key="payload" value="payload.getDDA_XML_MESSAGE()" /> 
                </map> 
        </property> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for the above question , spelsource is used in spring integration framework to read the data dynamically and pass it onto property file. as shown in below.

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter 
            channel="com.db.jdbc.serviceactivator.output" data-source="dataSource" 
            query="${int.jdbc.poller.outbound.ddaout.update.query}" 
            sql-parameter-source-factory="SpelSource" /> 

    <bean id="SpelSource" 
            class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory"> 
            <property name="parameterExpressions"> 
                    <map> 
                            <entry key="dda_rid_dda" value="payload.getMMI_RID_MSG_IN()" /> 
                            <entry key="response" value="headers.updateflag" /> 
                    </map> 
            </property> 
    </bean>
```